# ServiceWorker client.postMessage FIFO sequence

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-applications, output, service-worker

EDIT: I don't seem to be able to reproduce this without debug but then my testing hasn't really been "extensive". If you can help please see the code for a working example at: - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU There is a aaa_readme.txt and it's pretty straight forward documented code. Certainly regarding the already discussed SW messaging.

I am pretty sure that what I am seeing is just a side effect of the Chrome debugger intervention combined with various "alerts" in my code, but another set of eyes or greater knowledge in this area may solve my problem and point out something that I am doing wrong.

What I am seeing is, very occasionally, messages arriving to the client (onmessage) from the ServiceWorker (postMessage) in a different order from that in which they were written. If it's not the debugger then is must be my code.

If you look at the following output, "How can the **start** message event be delivered to the client **before** the INTRO message event?

See that SWIcnt is still at its initial value of -1 when the **start** message event arrives.

Console.log output (In correct order): -

```
SW Registered
TravelManagerPolyfill.js:177 Msg Sent to SW
travelmanager.html:162 Got SW command GrussGott
travelmanager.html:162 Got SW command start
TravelManagerPolyfill.js:177 Msg Sent to SW
travelmanager.html:162 Got SW command loiter
TravelManagerPolyfill.js:297 recalibrating
```

Output DIV content: - (***incorrect*** order)

```
<div class="log" id="logWindow">
Messages: -<br>
<span style="color:white">1:27:40 PM Kick off!</span><br>
1:27:52 PM 1:27:40 PM SWI-1 NaN 1 start lng: 115.8107681 lat: -31.982061499999997 +/- 1697<br>
<span style="color:red">1:27:55 PM New ServiceWorker instance 0</span><br>
1:28:37 PM 1:27:40 PM SWI0 1 2 loiter lng: 115.8107681 lat: -31.982061499999997 +/- 1697<br>
</div>
```

Client Code: -

```
var SWIcnt = -1;
var SWIhits = [];

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", SWMessage);

function SWMessage(e)
{
var resp = e.data;
console.log("Got SW command "+resp.cmd);

if (resp.cmd == INTRO) {
    SWIhits[++SWIcnt] = 0;
    logWindow.innerHTML += "<span style='color:red'>" + 
                        new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + 
                        " New ServiceWorker instance " + 
                        SWIcnt +"</span><br />" ;
    return;
}

SWIhits[SWIcnt]++

if (resp.cmd == ERROR) {
    logWindow.innerHTML += "<span style='color:yellow'>" + 
                        new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + 
                        " error from SW  " + 
                        resp.data.message +"</span><br />" ;
    return;
}

const prolog = "";
const epilog = "<br />";
var position = resp.data;
var outMessage = prolog + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + " " +
                new Date(position.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString() + " SWI" +
                SWIcnt + " " + SWIhits[SWIcnt] + " " + resp.serialNum + " " +
                resp.cmd + " lng: " + position.coords.longitude + " lat: " +
                position.coords.latitude + " +/- " + position.coords.accuracy +
                epilog; 
logWindow.innerHTML += outMessage;
}
```

And here is the relevant ServiceWorker code: -

```
var   doryRegister  = [];            // Meet someone new every day.
const INTRO         = "GrussGott";   // Tell clients we're new.


function sendClient(client, cmd, msg)
{                 
    if (!doryRegister[client.id]) {
        doryRegister[client.id] = 0;
        if (!postIt(client,{'cmd':INTRO})) return false;
    }

    return postIt(client,   
                    {
                    "cmd" : cmd,
                    "serialNum" : ++doryRegister[client.id],
                    "data" : msg
                    });
}

function postIt(client,msg)
{
    try {
        client.postMessage(msg)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Could not respond to client: "+e.message)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: And 15secs for the INTRO message event to turn up? What was it doing? Again, I have break-points and alerts and sometimes both debug windows open but how does that explain the reordering?

Comment: It seems like it's something with service worker lifecycle. Could you provide. It's possible that previous SW delivers START message, then new one takes over and sends the INTRO. Difficult to track without full code.

Comment: I'm just tidying up a full featured SSCCE to try to make it a bit easier. The crux is the SW code can't help but send INTRO "GrussGott" followed by "start". The console log agrees. The problem is the client message events arrive START --> INTRO. Sorry, I didn't trap the previous messages but more to come soon. Thanks.